# Design issue in C++: code reuse in interface centric design

Tags: c++, oop

The project has a goal: use interface centric design. Basically we declare classes of only public pure functions and have real classes inherit from them.

One question comes up now - how to reuse the utility functions?

Here is an example:

```
class InterF1 {
  public:
    int f1() = 0;
    int g1() = 0;   
}; 

class InterF2 {
  public:
    int f2() = 0;
}; 

class C1: public InterF1 {
  public:
    int f1();
    int g1();
};


class C2: public InterF1, InterF2 {
  public:
    int f1();
    int g1();
    int f2();
};
```

While I am implementing C1::f1() and C2::f1(), I see code duplication between these 2 functions. How should I remove the duplication?

Here are my thoughts:

1) I can add protected to interface class like this:

```
class InterF1 {
  public:
    int f1() = 0;
    int g1() = 0;   
  protected:
    int util();
    int convenient_var_calculated_by_util;
};
```

in the above design, C1::f1() and C2::f2() can both call util().

2) I can abstract a new interface:

```
class UtilI {
    public:
      int util(int in_var) = 0;
};
```

In this design, InterF1, C1 and C2 are changed to

```
class InterF1 {
  public:
    int f1(UtilI u) = 0;
    int g1() = 0;   
}; 

class C1: public InterF1 {
  public:
    int f1(UtilI u);
    int g1();
};


class C2: public InterF1, InterF2 {
  public:
    int f1(UtilI u);
    int g1();
    int f2();
};
```

and C1::f1() and C2::f1() both call UtilI API.

Solution 2 seems more aligned with our "interface centric" goal and it does look better. But I have one concern, InterF1 and InterF2 themselves should be higher level abstraction than UtilI which is more of implementation detail, am I mixing the 2 levels? Another words, if implementation changes later, I will need to come back to update f1() and f2() signature again, that does not sound right.

Solution 1 does seem handy, but it looks less "pure" to me, am I too much dogmatic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I would say you should put the common implementation in the base class - but you have a requirement that the base class is purely virtual.  So instead I'd recommend either:

1. **Create an intermediate implementation class**

   This approach is okay if every class that wants to implement `InterF2` also wants to implement `InterF1`.

   The approach is to implement

   ```
   class InterF1Impl: public InterF1 {
     public:
       int f1();
       int g1();
   }
   ```

   Then `C1` and `C2` can both be derived from `InterF1Impl` which implements the common `f1()` and `g1()` methods.

   However, this approach won't extend well if you have another class, `C3 : public InterF2`, which wants to share an implementation of `f2()` with `C2` but doesn't want to implement `InterF1`.

   An alternative (and better) approach is
2. **Use composition to include an implementation class**.

   In this approach, implement `InterF1Impl: public InterF1` as above, but instead of *deriving* `C1: public InterF1Impl`, let `InterF1Impl` be one part of the `C1` class.

   ```
   class C1: public InterF1 {
     private:
       InterF1Impl * f1impl;
     public:
       int f1();
       int g1();
   }
   ```

   The `C1::f1()` and `C1::g1()` methods simply call the corresponding methods from `f1impl`.

   This way, if you need a common implementation of `f2()`, then you can also implement `InterF2: public InterF2`, and `C2` can be implemented in a similar way:

   ```
   class C2: public InterF1, InterF2 {
     private:
       InterF1Impl * f1impl;
       InterF2Impl * f2impl;
     public:
       int f1(); /* calls f1impl->f1() */
       int g1(); /* calls f1impl->g1() */
       int f2(); /* calls f2impl->f2() */
   }
   ```

   And another class could just use the implementation of `InterF2` without also implementing `InterF1` if you later needed such a class.

Comment: A variant on what you're saying would be also to have either a class and/or series of plain utility functions that are only in the implementation of C1 and C2.  So they're included in the implementations, but are never exposed to the public interface.  That seems slightly simpler than having the utility classes pointed to in the class, which still "exposes" them as part of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd solution is better than the 1st one, but I would do it differently.

First of all, code reuse can be achieved via either inheritance or composition relationships between objects. In this case, the composition approach makes more sense, as I explain below.

The users of your classes probably don't care about the implementation of the `util()` method, or even its existence. So having the `UtilI` interface and making it a part of your public APIs seems unnecessary. Since the utility logic is a part of your implementation, not of the interface, this class should only be used in the implementation of your C1 and C2 classes. If you go that way, you likely don't need the `UtilI` interface, and can replace with just the concrete class `Util`. You can probably make this class stateless so it only has static methods. If not, then it could either be a singleton, or your classes can create their own instances (depending on what you need).

Interface-centric design is a fine goal, but it is important that you only expose things that should be public. That is an essential part of designing any API, which should be both **complete** and **minimal**.